# How can I store an image with the @GeneratedValue id in filename?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm new in Spring and I'd like to save a profile picture for a member. I'm using lombok and JPA.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Member {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date entryDate;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String function;
    private String picture;

    protected Member() {
        this.entryDate = new Date();
    }
```

I expect one POST with all the data. The Picture will be sent as basic64 encoded String, but in the DB should only be stored a link to the image. To find and identify the right picture for each member, I'd like to name them with the generated id. This is what I already did:

```
public void setPicture(String picture){
    File folder = new File("images");
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    String[] base = picture.split(",");
    String[] type = base[0].split("/|;");
    this.picture = "images/" + id + "." + type[1];
    try {
        byte[] imageByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base[1]);
        new FileOutputStream(this.picture).write(imageByte);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO: what is best practice here?
        this.picture = "images/default.jpg";
    }
}
```

My Problem is that the id at this point does not exist. Is there a way to invoke this method later, after an id is generated, or should I choose a different approach to solve this problem? I didn't find any tutorials or questions, which solve this problem.

Comment: You can use an Interceptor to write the image to disk after the entity is saved. See http://blog.janjonas.net/2010-02-17/hibernate-interceptor-update-entity-property-on-update-on-save

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use it like that:

```
entityManager.persist(member);
member.setPicture("pictureString");
entityManager.merge(member);
```